# Springboot JPA application and failover of primary node in Innodb Cluster

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, cluster-computing, innodb, failover

I am prototyping the testing of an HA architecture. The basic architecture comprises of an InnoDB Cluster consisting of 3 servers, running in single-primary mode, a instance of MySqlRouter and a Springboot application running SpringBootDataJPA.

The InnoDB cluster checks out fine when I manually (via the MySQLRouter) enter/retrieve data and then fail the primary InnoDB node. One of the secondary nodes gets promoted and manages the subsequent queries.

However when I do the same and the database interactions are managed by a springboot application, (the jpa connection string points to the MySqlRouter R/W port), when the primary InnoDB node is failed the springboot application crashes with a bunch of SocketExceptions from the MySQL JDBC driver.

How can I make the springboot application be resilient to a failover of the primary node in an InnoDB cluster, when connecting to the cluster via MySQLRouter? Are there some specialised JPA configuration settings that need to be used, or do I need to manage this within code in a specialised connection manager?

Many thanks in advance for any help with this,
C